# Find out if Docker volume mounted with rshared option

Tags: docker

I need to implement different bash logic within a script depending on whether a folder was docker volume mounted using rshared or without rshared option.

Any ideas if that is possible and how the bash logic looks like?

Thank you

PS. I can run the check logic on the host or even within the running Docker container.

Comment: Question is ambiguous, try describing indicators for `a folder is a docker volume mounted using rshared` .

Comment: I am mounting the folder using -v /hostfolder:/host:rshared command line options.
And now I need to find out if the folder was mounted with or without rshared.

This rshared is a binding propagation setting: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation

Comment: put it in question.

Comment: It seems this is what I was searching for: https://serverfault.com/questions/769062/how-do-i-check-if-a-bind-mount-on-linux-is-private-or-shared